# Counting Number of Holes in an Image of Cheese

Tags: machine-learning, python, computer-vision, supervised-learning, image-recognition

I've been assigned a project that involves writing a script to detect the number of holes in an image of cheese. My background in AI is quite limited, so I was wondering if anyone could give me a good starting point. I'm aware that Python is the best language for this sort of stuff, so I was wondering which ML model would be most effective at solving this issue. Our main project is using a .NET framework, so I need to make sure that it can be run from C# (I believe you can wrap the finished model in a REST API). Assume it's a supervised learning model, but feel free to suggest an unsupervised model as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of holes detected would be limited to the number of holes visible in the image (I mean obviously!:P). So you cannot count the holes for example at the back of the cheese since they wont be visible.

With that being said this is a problem which requires a **CNN (Convolution Neural Network)**. You could train an object detection model to **detect the holes** in the image. Then simply **add them up**. This is the most straightforward/easy way to solve your problem. Try using [YoloV5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)
as this is an easy model to train and is also state of art!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look into this model.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any research about cheese hole counting, but this problem resembles counting people in a crowd or blood cells to me. There is a plethora of scientific papers about that and a few approaches you can use.:

1. You can use the YOLO approach to identify holes first, and then count them. A well-cited example for blood cell counting:

Alam, M. M., & Islam, M. T. (2019). Machine learning approach of automatic identification and counting of blood cells. Healthcare technology letters, 6(4), 103-108.

2. Regression - you can attempt to use CNN to predict an exact number of holes. A friend of mine used it for counting people in the crowd, but let's grab a piece of literature you can read about it:

Patwal, A., Diwakar, M., Tripathi, V., & Singh, P. (2023). Crowd counting analysis using deep learning: A critical review. Procedia Computer Science, 218, 2448-2458.

3. Density estimation - something interesting I hadn't known and stumbled across in the second article - you can try to predict a map of the density of holes upon the image.

I hope you find there a method suitable for your project :)

Comment: Thanks for all the reference papers. I will read through them when I get the chance. Much appreciated.